# Add history entry to the browser without changing the hash or any other parts of the URL

Tags: javascript, browser-state

Is there a trick (with an iframe maybe...) to add an history entry to the browser without changing the hash or any other parts of the URL, while being compatible with older browsers (not older than ie8 - without pushstate)?

**I know it sounds weird but here is the logic behind this question:**

I'm doing a single page application and I want to get rid of 
modals as popups. I use the same techniques but instead of placing a div above the actual page, I would like to hide the entire page and show only the div representing the modal.

This works great, but now that the modal is taking the entire page, the user tends (and it is perfectly normal) to click on the back button to cancel the action and return to the previous page (which is hidden while the modal is displayed).

I know I could navigate to a different page (by changing the hash) but I don't want the URL to change since the destination is not a page on it's own but only a modal (it would not make sense to copy the URL of the modal and pass it to someone else or bookmarking the modal - as any normal modal inside a popup).

I would also need to be able to remove this entry in the cases where the user has completed the action (in the modal) or clicked on the cancel button.

Comment: If the modal is logically not a URL state, why would you want to treat it as such? you can use `replaceState` , but honestly, I'm not sure I understand the need. Unrelated to the actual scenario, this is an interesting question.

Comment: Yes, indeed, very interesting, I faced a similar problem a while ago, I ended up with `replaceState` but I would like to know about this too, I couldn't find much info on the topic...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As I said, since the modal is not a popup anymore, the user tends to use the back button to cancel the action.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Furthermore, I appreciate the modal since it makes the user focus on the action, but I don't like the div above the page solution since it does not work well with mobile (one reason among others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that explains what could be a solution (with an iframe...): [from the book Ajax Design Patterns](http://books.google.ca/books?id=vexpJ-XqYG0C&pg=PA519&lpg=PA519&dq=create%20%22history%20entry%22%20iframe&source=bl&ots=3R9Darql4N&sig=Hv2YbymVAXN2nk1v8pU_UhbYVag&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D82cUcaUGIebygGH84DgBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=create%20%22history%20entry%22%20iframe&f=false)

I will give it a try soon and get you posted on the result.